# ssh into a server using .ssh/config alias & run an alias on the server in the same time

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

#### On my laptop

Inside `~/.ssh/config` file I have this:

```
Host <serverAlias>
    HostName 127.0.0.1 #Server IP
    User <username>
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

#### On the server

Inside `~/.bashrc` I have this alias:

```
alias runcomman="ls -al"
```

#### What I want to do is

In my terminal I want to type `ssh <serverAlias> <something>` to ssh into the server & run the alias on the server.

How can I do this?

Comment: If bash is your login shell on the server then `ssh serverAlias runcomman` does find aliases from `.bashrc`. Is this not working? What is your login shell on the server (`ssh serverAlias 'ps $$'`)?

Comment: This is what I got when ran the command `7493 ?        Rs     0:00 ps 7493`

Comment: Oh, your shell is optimizing tail calls (which is consistent with bash). `ssh serverAlias 'ps $$'; alias`, then

Comment: It listed all my "local" aliases not the server one. I want to run an alias on the server not locally, maybe I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

The ".bashrc" file is only processed within "interactive shells". There are multiple question around the Stack Exchange network:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work
- [ssh, start a specific shell, and run a command on the remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/ssh-start-a-specific-shell-and-run-a-command-on-the-remote-machine)

There are two options for you: modify bash settings on the server or startup your ssh command with a prefix.

Comment: Actually, there's an oddity in bash: it also runs `.bashrc` in non-interactive shells whose parent is called `rshd` or `sshd`.

Comment: I tried most of the solutions mentioned in these threads, none of them worked.