# ssh, start a specific shell (ash), and source your environment on the remote machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, openssh, ash

This is a kind of follow-up question to this question: [ssh, start a specific shell, and run a command on the remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20729/114401), except more-specifically regarding `ash`, and focused on the fact that sourcing a .bashrc file as part of starting the shell in the ssh session doesn't work for me.

I'm on an embedded Linux device which has a busybox version of `sh` and `ash`, but there is no `bash`. We share a common username (`root`), and a common execution environment.

I'd like to have a few custom aliases and a custom `PS1` Prompt String 1 variable, however.

Here is an example normal ssh session. Note that I'm using `sshpass` to pass my password to `ssh`, with my password stored in the `~/pw` file.

You can see that the default shell is `-sh` and there are no aliases. The default `PS1` prompt string also shows no path.

> ```
> $ sshpass -f ~/pw ssh root@192.168.0.2
> [root@device]$ echo $0
> -sh
> [root@device]$ alias
> [root@device]$
> ```

The device has no `bash`, but it does have `ash`, which apparently is bash-like. So, I want to make that my shell as I ssh in. I also want to copy Ubuntu's default `~/.bashrc` file, located in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` on the Ubuntu machine I'm ssh-ing *from*, to the device at `/tmp/.bashrc` so I can source it, and I want my ssh command to do that. I can't copy to `~/.bashrc` on the remote device because the home dir is read-only.

I tried the following, but get the following error:

cmd:

```bsh
sshpass -f ~/pw scp /etc/skel/.bashrc root@192.168.0.2:/tmp/.bashrc \
&& sshpass -f ~/pw ssh -t root@192.168.0.2 '. /tmp/.bashrc'
```

result:

> ```
> Connection to 192.168.0.2 closed.
> ```

No ssh session was established.

I then tried the following command, with the following result, showing that sourcing did not work, although the `ash` shell was entered.

> ```
> $ sshpass -f ~/pw scp /etc/skel/.bashrc root@192.168.0.2:/tmp/.bashrc \
> && sshpass -f ~/pw ssh -t root@192.168.0.2 '. /tmp/.bashrc; ash'
> ~ # echo $0
> ash
> ~ # alias
> ~ #
> ```

I can run `. /tmp/.bashrc` manually now though, and it works fine. Notice how after sourcing, which works, I have an improved prompt string and new aliases:

> ```
> ~ # . /tmp/.bashrc
> ash: /tmp/.bashrc: line 16: shopt: not found
> ash: /tmp/.bashrc: line 24: shopt: not found
> ash: /tmp/.bashrc: line 111: shopt: not found
> root@device:~# alias
> l='ls -CF'
> alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '"'"'s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'"'"')"'
> la='ls -A'
> ll='ls -alF'
> ```

You also see the ash errors from line 16, 24, and 111 due to `shopt` not being found. Even if I comment those out in the .bashrc file I send over, the results as shown above are still the same.

**How can I get my above command to work? I'd like it to ssh in, set the shell to something more like bash, and source my `/tmp/.bashrc` file I scp'ed over.**

---

On a similar embedded device which *does* have `bash` installed, this cmd works perfectly, [as I document in my repo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home/.ssh#command):

```bsh
sshpass -f ~/pw scp /etc/skel/.bashrc root@192.168.0.2:/tmp \
&& sshpass -f ~/pw ssh -t root@192.168.0.2 'bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc'
```

For `bash`, using `bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc` at the end of the ssh cmd is what I need. But, for the device withOUT `bash`, I need help getting this behavior with `ash` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you running `ash`? A system with busybox is unlikely to have two different shells. (It's technically possible that `/bin/sh` is not the same shell as `/bin/ash`, but it would be a very unlikely setup on an embedded device.)

Apart from a few simple aliases or functions, very little of the typical content of `.bashrc` is likely to work in ash (or in any shell that isn't bash). Things that won't work include `shopt`, key bindings, prompt settings, any function that uses non-POSIX extension, any alias that refers to commands not present on the embedded device.

> ```
> … ssh -t root@192.168.0.2 '. /tmp/.bashrc; ash'
> ```

You're reading `/tmp/.bashrc` in the original shell, then running a different shell program. That different program doesn't inherit any of the shell's internal settings such as aliases. It's a completely different problem from [ssh, start a specific shell, and run a command on the remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/ssh-start-a-specific-shell-and-run-a-command-on-the-remote-machine) which is about reading `.profile`, which sets environemnt variables, which *are* inherited.

BusyBox's ash reads commands from the file whose name is in `$ENV` when it starts interactively. (BusyBox's sh can be either ash or hush; since you have an `ash` command, yours is ash.) So you can set `ENV` to the name of the file where you want to read commands.

```
… ssh -t root@192.168.0.2 'export ENV=/tmp/.bashrc; sh -i'
```

Comment: Even when both /bin/sh and /bin/ash are symlinked to busybox, they probably behave differently.  Busybox looks at `argv[0]` to find out what installable module and options for the module to use.  So /bin/sh is likely "run Busybox ash shell with the more-POSIX flag"

Comment: Documentation for `ash` which mentions `ENV` variable: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash

Comment: Setting `ENV` worked, as you said! Here is my final alias. I put this in `~/.bash_aliases` on my Ubuntu machine and can now use `gs_ssh` to ssh into the device with the environment that I want. I customized the .bashrc file to my needs. Final alias and command: `alias gs_ssh="sshpass -f ~/pw scp path/to/custom/.bashrc root@192.168.0.2:/tmp && sshpass -f ~/pw ssh -t -o 'ServerAliveInterval 60' root@192.168.0.2 'export ENV=/tmp/.bashrc; ash'"`. Note that using `ash` vs `ash -i` at the end seems to make no difference, perhaps because the shell is already interactive since we are using `ssh -t`?

Comment: Gilles, to answer your question: `Why are you running ash?` I suspect @BenVoigt is right in his comment above. When I run `busybox --help` to see a list of all functions inside it, I see `ash` and `sh` separately. [My understanding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395779/what-exactly-is-busybox-ash/1374973#1374973) is that `ash` is a lightweight substitute for `bash`, whereas `sh` is not.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Your understanding is wrong. BusyBox's comes with two different implementations of the sh language: one called ash, and one called hush. (And to add to the naming confusion, there are other implementations of sh also called ash.) Both can be considered a “lightweight substitute for bash”. Ash is a little more complete than hush but that comes with more code size, hence the two choices. On a given system, you only have one of them. `sh` **is** ash, it's available under both names, and I don't think BusyBox cares which name you use.

Comment: @BenVoigt BusyBox is a small implementation and doesn't bother with extra code to distinguish between backward-compatible and POSIX-compatible modes. It has many compilation options, but avoids runtime complexity. Checking in the [source](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c), I can't find any place where it cares whether it was called `ash` or `sh`, or any mention of a “more-POSIX” mode. What makes you think they behave differently?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are embedded systems with busybox having both ash and sh, and sh being hush, not ash. There's a `SH_IS_HUSH` configuration for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your default shell is stored in the `/etc/passwd` file. Any user can change its default shell with the `chsh` command. The authorized shells are listed in `/etc/shells`. Of course, bash should be present before switching to this shell.

Comment: If I run: `chsh`, I get: `-sh: chsh: not found`.

Comment: I guess some embedded Linux system doesn’t contains all common commands. `/etc/password` could be edited by root with `vi`… but if the system is stripped down, it may lack bash too ! Start verifying the presence of bash !

Comment: At the top of my question: "I'm on an embedded Linux device which has a busybox version of `sh` and `ash`, but there is no `bash`." If I run `bash` I get `-sh: bash: not found`. I'm pretty sure that's the whole point of `ash`: it is a light-weight substitute for `bash`. See: [Ask Ubutu: What exactly is Busybox / Ash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/395779/327339)

Comment: I see my `PS1` Prompt String 1 defined in `/etc/profile.d/prompt.sh` it looks like, as `export PS1="\[\033[1;34m\][\u@\h]$\[\033[0m\] "`.

Comment: You can change it in your `.profile`.  `\w` is a synonymous of your current directory. Then you can set `PS1='\u@\h:\w\$'` and get your current directory in your prompt… like with bash.