# For a same unix or linux user, different sets of environment variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables, alias, tcsh, key-authentication

I'm using `tcsh`, and for a specific project every member of my team connects to a server with the same user. (This is something we cannot change).

The situation arises because I want to have some custom environment variables and aliases, and to do so I have my own .tcshrc file (namely `.tcshrc_cust`) which I load as the first action when connecting to that machine:

```
source .tcshrc_cust
```

and even though this works pretty well, I'm experiencing a problem when using `vim`: if I get to the shell from inside vim (with `:sh`) I fall into a normal shell, without my custom env. vars. and aliases.

Is there a solution for this, besides using a different user in that machine?

---

**SOLUTION (given by @Shawn):**

I prefixed my key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` with:

```
command="setenv subuser noz; tcsh"
```

and wrote at the end of `.tcshrc` file these lines:

```
if ($?subuser) then
    source .tcshrc_$subuser;
endif
```

And everything works fine now.

Comment: If you're logging in over ssh, there are more convenient methods: see [Is there a way to push shell config information when SSHing to a host?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14919/is-there-a-way-to-push-shell-config-information-when-sshing-to-a-host/14948)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `.tcshrc` check a special environment variable (like `subuser`), and conditionally `source .tcshrc_cust`. When you log in, run `subuser=nozimica tcsh`. It will get that enironment variable and execute your custom rc script. In addition, vim's `:sh` command will work.  You can even make it fancy and `source .tcshrc_$subuser`; that way everyone could do it.

You can skip the part where you run `subuser=nozimica tcsh` when you login by having ssh run it for you. If you setup ssh key authentication, then in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server, you can prefix your key with `command="subuser=nozimica tcsh"`, and ssh will run that command for you.

Comment: Your answer has been extremely useful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can send along environment variables from your local machine using SSH.

For example, put `export FOO_USER="$USER"` (in `tcsh`'s version of `.bash_profile`) or `FOO_USER=joe ssh remote-host` (on the command line) on your local machine. Edit your `~/.ssh/config` to include this: `SendEnv LANG LC_* FOO_USER`.

Then, on the remote server, you can check for that variable in the `.bash_profile` (or what have you in `tcsh`), and perform the appropriate action:

```
if [ "$FOO_USER" = 'joe' ]; then
    export PS1='--[ Joe rules ]-- \u@\h \w \$ ';
    source tcsh.joe;
elif [ "$FOO_USER" = 'jane' ]; then
    alias ll='ls -Al';
fi
```

By default, the SSH server only accepts `LANG` and `LC_*`, so if you cannot edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server to add `AccceptEnv LANG LC_* FOO_USER`, you could hack around it by abusing the `LC_*` variables, e.g. `LC_FOO_USER=joe`. Update your `.bash_profile`s (or rather, the appropriate local and remote `tcsh` files) accordingly.

Comment: This may seem like more work than the `authorized_keys` approach, and that's because it is. :-) However, it also works for non-key authentication or even when —gasp— the private key is shared among several users.

Answer (score 1):

My team and I have been facing a similar issue with a shared account. We came up with basically the same solution, optimizing it a tiny bit.

Here's what we do. (We use `ksh`, I don't know much about `tcsh` but I assume it's pretty similar).

- Strip down `.tcshrc` to a bare minimum, so that it's barely usable any more.
- Force every user to use a `.tcshrc_cust`

And in the original `tcshrc` add something like that:

```
 alias u1='source .tcshrc_user1'
 alias u2='source .tcshrc_user2'
 alias u3='source .tcshrc_user3'
```

The idea is that it's more convenient to enter just 2 letters than a whole command. Also if the whole team is doing it, it becomes more adopted and easier to maintain.

I'm not saying it's a perfect solution, and I've been looking for the same thing as you for a while now, it's the best I could come up with. Let's hope somebody else has a better idea :)

Comment: Indeed I already follow that strategy, so I have my own alias "sourcing" my custom `.tcshrc`. Thank you anyway! :D